# Find missing rows based on two columns and date series – Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I try to search for missing periods (Year and Month = 201508) AND for each employe signature 'AA'. Searching one column works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM generate_series('2014-12-31','2016-12-31', interval '1 month') AS dates 
WHERE to_char(dates,'YYYYMM') NOT IN (SELECT ts_per FROM ts)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0cafa/4

The output of this is just the missing month

Like March is missing.

But I want the output to be per employee as well. Missing record for jan and march for JD and AS for feb and march. BB are missing all three months.

```
JD 201502
JD 201503 
AS 201501
AS 201503
BB 201501
BB 201502
BB 201503
```

Here is my newbie attempt to add employee to the search which fails:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0cafa/5

ERROR: syntax error

TIA for any clue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a temp list using WITH. Searching the table using this temp list did the trick

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0cafa/12

```
WITH per AS 
(SELECT concat(emp_id,to_char(generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-03-01', interval '1 month'),'YYYYMM')) as signper FROM emp)
SELECT * FROM per where signper not in(SELECT concat(ts_sign,ts_per) FROM ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not sure what you want... but would recommend you outer join

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-03-01', interval '1 month') AS dates
left outer join ts on concat(ts_sign,ts_per) = concat(ts_sign,to_char(dates,'YYYYMM'))
```

to see same and missing, and :

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2015-01-01','2015-03-01', interval '1 month') AS dates
left outer join ts on concat(ts_sign,ts_per) = concat(ts_sign,to_char(dates,'YYYYMM'))
where ts_per is null
```

to see only missing

Comment: Sorry, some missing rows are still missing :-)